# jQuery click (only click) not working

Tags: jquery, click

So here is the jQuery code (as simple as possible) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#test").click(function () {
    alert('Works!');
  });
});
```

and the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" ></script>
<p id="test">ss</p>
```

and funny thing, whatever I put after `click()`, doesn't work, BUT if I use `hide()`, `append()` or whatever instead of `click()`, it is working. What is the problem? I'm using the SMARTY, I simplified the code a little, because this page is included into layout.tpl but nevertheless; why only `click()` function doesn't work?!

Comment: And you are putting the code after the click event inside the DOM ready handler, right ?

Comment: When you say the click doesn't work, are you saying that you click on the #test element and it doesn't show the alert?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq] if you haven't already. You've done a fine job on a first question, so I probably don't even need to point you to [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) either. If you don't mind, please create a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This simple snippet works http://jsfiddle.net/R4pvE/, can you give more info? What is the linked test.js script, what it contains? Errors in console?

Comment: Funny.  There is more content in that page (layout excluded) ?

Comment: @mattc - yes, exactly.

Comment: @Edward - test.js contains the Jquery code I put above.

Comment: @Mati, did you check the network panel in the browser's debug tools to be certain that `test.js` was loaded?

Comment: @fliim - no, this is the only content there is.
zzzzBov - I'm using firebug and it shows it loaded. Moreover - as I said, other functions work, just click() creates a problem.

Comment: @Mati As Edward mentioned, the snippet above works. There's likely a problem in the context of your larger page, such as duplicate IDs.

Comment: Or duplicate $("#test").click

Comment: Ok, i found something:
so this page is included between <div id="page"> </div>
and the css for #page looks like that:
#page

{
    margin: 10px 160px;
    width: 1180px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
and when I remove it - the JQuery click() works. What the..? :P

Comment: Works with styles here: http://jsfiddle.net/R4pvE/1/, tested in all win browsers; the problem must be different

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5TWGF/ - it is working here, but to make it work on my localhost i have to remove "margin: 10px 160px;". Why?
EDIT: ok, so i found out that..it actually is working, but i have to click somewhere above the paragraph to make the alert appear. This is weird..

Comment: @fliim A duplicate `.click` event would just result in 2 events firing (unless you use `stopPropagation()`).

Comment: You have to provide the full code running on local there is something in your full html/css.

Comment: @Edward - http://jsfiddle.net/5TWGF/1/ and here You can see the problem. The area that makes click() is removed to the right ( in this editor - on my localhost it is a little bit higher ). I'm sorry that names of id's are strange but they're in my native language :P I noticed that "margin" is responsible of this situation.

Comment: @Mati It is the issue with positioning of the elements. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are getting is with the `CSS` positioning of the elements.

The div with id `menu` is stacked over the div with the id `strona` as the former have given width `200px` and `position:absolute`. So the click on the text is not working but the click on the div further right of text is working.

So in this case if you add

```
`position:absolute`
```

to the div `strona`, it works as expected.

Check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5TWGF/2/).

Comment: Thank You very much :)
( dunno if I should add comment or answer )